# Transposing a 2 dimensional matrix in Erlang

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

Given a matrix like below, transform it, say, 90 degrees into the second matrix below. How would you go about doing this in the cleanest way possible? Short/succinct/clear solutions where the point is easy to grasp is preferred.

From

```
[[A1,A2,A3],
 [B1,B2,B3],
 [C1,C2,C3]]
```

To

```
[[A1,B1,C1],
 [A2,B2,C2],
 [A3,B3,C3]]
```

**Edit:** I realize it was not clear from original question. I'd like to know how to do this in **Erlang**.

Comment: This is called transposing the matrix: a[j,i] = a[i, j]

Comment: Thanks; I'm changing the title.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simplifying the solutions already given, you can do it in as short as:

```
-module(transp).

-export([transpose/1]).

transpose([[]|_]) -> [];
transpose(M) ->
  [lists:map(fun hd/1, M) | transpose(lists:map(fun tl/1, M))].
```

Comment: Tested solution - this was what I was thinking of.

Comment: I like this solution, very short and elegant, and easy to convince yourself that it must be correct.

Answer (score 4):

In functional programming languages, the usual approach for matrix transposition is to use `unzip`.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to point in the right direction, but I still don't see in practice how to do this.

Comment: If you convert your example from a list of lists to a list of three-tuples, then you can use `unzip3` directly to experiment. Writing a version of `unzip` that takes a list of lists should be straightforward, once you get how `unzip` works.

Comment: However [`unzip/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#unzip-1) and [`unzip/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#unzip3-1) are limited to two- and three-dimensional matrices respectively. There are no `unzip4`, `unzip5` etc. in stdlib :-(

Comment: That was my issue as well, not being able to generalize the unzip version.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my sample solution:

```
-module(transp).

-export([transpose/1]).

transpose(L) ->
     transpose_do([], L).

transpose_do(Acc, [[]|_]) ->
     lists:reverse(Acc);
transpose_do(Acc, M) ->
     Row = lists:foldr(
          fun(Elem, FoldAcc) ->
                    [hd(Elem) | FoldAcc]
          end,
          [],
          M),
     transpose_do([Row|Acc], lists:map(fun(X) -> tl(X) end, M)).
```

Test:

```
1> M = [[a1,a2,a3],[b1,b2,b3],[c1,c2,c3]].
[[a1,a2,a3],[b1,b2,b3],[c1,c2,c3]]
2> transp:transpose(M).   
[[a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,c2],[a3,b3,c3]]
```

Comment: By the way, it works for matrices of any size, not only for square matrices; e. g. `[[a1,a2,a3,a4], [b1,b2,b3,b4], [c1,c2,c3,c4], [d1,d2,d3,d4]]` will also do as an input ;-)

Comment: This is a nice answer indeed!

Comment: Sure, I meant `[[a1,a2,a3], [b1,b2,b3], [c1,c2,c3], [d1,d2,d3]]` in my first comment above.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an implementation that I think I got from the Haskell standard library:

```
%% Transpose rows and columns in a list of lists. Works even if sublists
%% are not of same length. Empty sublists are stripped.
transpose([[X | Xs] | Xss]) ->
    [[X | [H || [H | _] <- Xss]]
     | transpose([Xs | [T || [_ | T] <- Xss]])];
transpose([[] | Xss]) -> transpose(Xss);
transpose([]) -> [].
```

Compact and slightly mind-bending.

Comment: For anyone curious, the Elixir version of this would be:  
`def transpose([[x | xs] | xss]), do: [[x | (for [h | _] <- xss, do: h)] | transpose([xs | (for [_ | t] <- xss, do: t)])]`  
You should be able to translate the rest from the above easily enough. I can't paste the whole thing here because Stupid Stackoverflow Comment Limitations™

Answer (score 2):

What you are showing is not a matrix rotation, but rather matrix transposition. If you call the first matrix A and the second B then you have

```
A[i,j] = B[j,i]
```

To go from A to B you just need two nested loops with i = 1 to n and j = i+1 to n and at each iteration you swap the off-diagonal entries using a temporary variable.

Comment: Yes, but the question was how to do this in Erlang.