# Erlang lists:zip3 .. but more than 3

Tags: list, erlang, zip

So we can use this function in erlang

```
DataList = lists:zip3(Data1, Data2, Data3)
```

to generate:

```
Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
1> Data1 = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"].
["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
2> Data2 = ["aaa2","bbb2","ccc2"].
["aaa2","bbb2","ccc2"]
3> Data3 = ["aaa3","bbb3","ccc3"].
["aaa3","bbb3","ccc3"]
4> DataList = lists:zip3(Data1, Data2, Data3).                                   
[{"aaa","aaa2","aaa3"},
 {"bbb","bbb2","bbb3"},
 {"ccc","ccc2","ccc3"}]
```

I need something that can do this automatically:

```
DataList = lists:zipN(Data1, Data2, Data3, ... Data N)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write your own zipN function like this:

```
zipN([]) ->
    [];
zipN(ListOfLists) ->
    zipN([], ListOfLists, [], []).

zipN(Ts, [], E, Acc) ->
    zipN([], lists:reverse(Ts), [], [list_to_tuple(lists:reverse(E)) | Acc]);

zipN(Ts, [[Head | Tail] | ListOfLists], E, Acc) ->
    zipN([Tail | Ts], ListOfLists, [Head | E], Acc);

zipN([], _, [], Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc).
```

Comment: your solution doesn't work for zipN(["a", ""]).

Adding as a second clause(??) to zipN/4:

`zipN(_, [[] | _], _, Acc) ->
  lists:reverse(Acc);`

will catch that problem at least. This looks like something QuickCheck or PropEr should be useful for, unfortunately I can't try that until tomorrow..

Comment: i dont think it is a good decision, try to explain: as you can see, my first argument called `ListOfLists`. As you ofc already know, strings in erlang is a simple lists with numbers. In your example you provide 2 lists as input value, length of 1st list =:= 1, and length of second list =:= 0. Dont think this is good to try to fix this problem with input values.

Comment: Fair enough, I hadn't noticed that in Erlang zip works only on equal length lists... but I could point out that your zipN(["", "x"]) and zipN(["ab", "xyz"]) do appear to succeed :-)

Comment: Ouch, seems like a bug :-D. I could propound a little bit ugly solution, to change zipN/1 with such code: `zipN([]) ->
    [];
zipN(ListsOfLists = [H | _]) ->
    L1 = length(H),
    true = lists:all(fun(X) ->
        length(X) =:= L1
    end, ListsOfLists),
    zipN([], ListsOfLists, [], []).` But since length/1 has O(N) complexity, this is not good. I`ll think about it today, maybe it should be completly rewrited

Answer (score 1):

You can't do literally this (except by using `parse_transform`), because Erlang functions can't have variable number of arguments. Your function would have to accept a list of lists:

```
DataList = lists:zipN([Data1, Data2, Data3, ... DataN])
```

This can be done by [transposing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389254/transposing-a-2-dimensional-matrix-in-erlang) the list and then [converting](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_tuple-1) every element of the result to a tuple.